# Separating Ruby Code which requires a block with Partials

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, block, partials

I want to use

```
<% form_tag ( <<variables from partial here>> ) do %>
```

on a partial;  problem is on the IDE it already is trying to tell me I have invalid code; this is because the "DO" is to be paired with an "END". I cannot end on the partial itself; because there is some content after the "DO" which is on the page where the partial is called.

How do I use the form_tag in the partial while using the content I have from the page which called the partial?

Comment: This feels like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. I would argue that opening a ERB block in one partial and closing it in another is obviously the wrong approach. All tags (even HTML tag) that are opened in a partial should be closed in the same partial. Otherwise your code will be error-prone and hard to maintain. It feels to my like splitting the pages into even more partials or use nested partials might be a better solution. But this depends on your needs. Can you please elaborate on your example and explain what you try to achieve.

Comment: @spickermann what you described is what I am trying to achieve. i am trying to avoid nested partials due to complications. but it seems i have no choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're in a very sticky situation. This is what I think you've got from your description:

```
#partial_1
<% form_tag (:model_name) do %>

#partial_2
<% form_contents %>
<% end %>

#controller
@model = Model.load
render(partial1 << partial2)
```

You may have to correct me if I'm wrong, but is it possible instead to do this?

```
#controller
@model = Model.load
render(partial_1)

#partial_1
<% form_tag ... %>
<%  render(partial_2) %>
<% end %>

#partial_2
<% all the form guts %>
```

If you're using straight ruby you're probably using the ERB library and you are [binding](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new-label-Example) every time, which should keep the variables live all the way through.